# Atomic Rsync? cron'd backup of regularly changing directory to remote: insuring one complete backup?

Tags: linux, backup, rsync

I've got a directory that changes regularly, but whose files are related.  I want to `rsync` that to a remote location, insuring that I always have one complete set of files at the remote.  That is, if I have one complete backup, I want that preserved until I have a second complete one, in order to insure that any network interruption does not destroy the integrity of the first.  If you think about it, `--backup` doesn't work, because it won't be clear if a not-backed-up file is part of the first complete backup, or the second incomplete one.

While what I want to do is scriptable, I'm thinking there's got to be a canned solution somewhere.  I gather `rdiff-backup` would do it, rolling back partial backups, but I can't get that installed on the target machine.  Does anyone have any other leads?

Comment: Is rsync literally the only thing you can have installed on the remote machine? There are various existing backup tools which can handle snapshots in their own format; some of them would be fine with standard SFTP access while others need their specific backend to be installed

Comment: Ya, it's managed, so if I need to be able to install something over there, it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the proper term for this is that I want a backup that is "atomic."  The `--delay-updates` switch is termed in the `man` page, "a little more atomic," doing all the deletions and moves, right at the end.  It worked for me, like this:

```
HOME="/home/me"
BACKUPFOLDER="$HOME/Backup/"
DIRECTORYLOG="$BACKUPFOLDER/<directory>.log"

NICERSYNC="nice -n 19 ionice -c 3 /usr/bin/rsync"
REMOTEHOST="me@vps.com"
REMOTEBACKUPFOLDER="/home/me/Backup"

# partial-dir must be relative when using it with temp-dir
RSYNCSWITCHES="-acv --itemize-changes --delay-updates --delete-delay --partial-dir=<directory>-partial --temp-dir=$REMOTEBACKUPFOLDER/<directory>-temp"

$NICERSYNC $RSYNCSWITCHES "$BACKUPFOLDER/<directory>" $REMOTEHOST:\"$REMOTEBACKUPFOLDER\" &>> "$DIRECTORYLOG"
```

Though I don't really understand the details, when `--partial-dir` is used with `--temp-dir` in the context of `--delay-updates`, it needs to be [given a relative path](https://rsync.samba.narkive.com/th093gya/do-not-reply-bug-3461-new-rsync-is-not-atomic-when-temp-dir-is-on-different-device).

There is also a script, `atomic-rsync` in the `/usr/share/rsync/scripts` directory.  Quoting from the `man` page:

> See also the "atomic-rsync" perl script in the "support" subdir for an
> update algorithm that is even more atomic (it uses --link-dest and a
> parallel hierarchy of files).

The problem for me is, that's only for pulling to a local directory, rather than pushing to a remote.  I've scripted one that should do the job properly, below.  After the first successful backup, `<directory>` will always exist on the remote as a complete backup.  Interrupted backups will appear as `<directory>.1`, `<directory>.2`, etc.  Any one that `rsync`'s to completion, will be moved to `<directory>`, and the other `<directory>.n` will be deleted.

```
HOME="/home/me"
BACKUPFOLDER="$HOME/Backup/<directory>"
DIRECTORYLOG="$BACKUPFOLDER/<directory>.log"

LOCALFOLDER="/home/dev/Backup"
LOCALSUBFOLDER="Restic/<directory>"
LOCALSOURCE="$LOCALFOLDER/$LOCALSUBFOLDER"

REMOTEHOST="me@vps.com"
REMOTEHOME="/home/me"
REMOTEFOLDER="Backup"
REMOTESUBFOLDER="<directory>"
REMOTETARGET="$REMOTEFOLDER/$REMOTESUBFOLDER"

NICERSYNC="nice -n 19 ionice -c 3 /usr/bin/rsync"
SWITCHES="-ac --partial-dir=\"$REMOTEHOME/$REMOTETARGET-partial\""

errormsgandexit() {
    if [[ $1 -ne 0 ]]; then
        echo "$2"
        exit $1
    fi
}

ssherrormsgandexit() {
    SSHCONNECTERROR=255
    if [[ $1 -eq $SSHCONNECTERROR ]]; then
        echo "$2"
        exit $1
    fi
}

echo -e "\n$(date) Rsync <directory>\n--------------------" >> "$DIRECTORYLOG"

# If TARGET exists, we use that for links: 
ssh $REMOTEHOST "[[ -d \"$REMOTETARGET\" ]]" && SWITCHLINKS="--link-dest=\"$REMOTEHOME/$REMOTETARGET\""
ssherrormsgandexit $? "ssh connect failure while checking $REMOTETARGET directory." >> "$DIRECTORYLOG" 

# Find the smallest n such that TARGET.n doesn't exist. use TARGET.1-(n-1) for links.
declare -i n=1
while ssh $REMOTEHOST "[[ -d \"$REMOTETARGET.$n\" ]]"; ! ((RETURN=$?)); do
    SWITCHLINKS="$SWITCHLINKS --link-dest=\"$REMOTEHOME/$REMOTETARGET.$((n++))\""
done
ssherrormsgandexit $RETURN "ssh connect failure while checking $REMOTETARGET.$n directory." >> "$DIRECTORYLOG" 

SWITCHESLINKS="$SWITCHES $SWITCHLINKS"

# now I am free to copy to TARGET.n:
$NICERSYNC $SWITCHESLINKS "$LOCALSOURCE/" $REMOTEHOST:\"$REMOTETARGET.$n\" >> "$DIRECTORYLOG"
errormsgandexit $? "rsync error, code $?." # >> "$DIRECTORYLOG" 

# if rsync was successful, just keep the most recent complete TARGET
ssh $REMOTEHOST "([[ ! -d \"$REMOTETARGET\" ]] || rm -r \"$REMOTETARGET\") && \
                mv \"$REMOTETARGET.$n\" \"$REMOTETARGET\" && \
                ([[ ! -d \"$REMOTETARGET.1\" ]] || rm -r \"$REMOTETARGET.\"*)" >> "$DIRECTORYLOG"
RETURN=$?
ssherrormsgandexit $RETURN "ssh connect failure while reordering $REMOTETARGET\* directories." >> "$DIRECTORYLOG"
errormsgandexit $RETURN "error when reorganizing $REMOTETARGET* directories." >> "$DIRECTORYLOG"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you work with opened files like a database, a direct `rsync` can be a bad idea, since `rsync` won’t read atomically all the blocks of all the files of the database. The most atomic way would need a system with snapshots enabled. This needs a dedicated `lvm` partition, or a file system like `btrfs` or `zfs`. When the partition is snapshoted, your `rsync` can work freely on a stable set of files. The `--delay-updates` may be used to make remote application *more* atomic.

Comment: Ya, thanks Frederic. The files are stable while I'm rsync'ing them. I do have btrfs and snapshots, but they are actually not needed in this case.  Here, it's the network going down as I'm pusing to the remote that I'm worried about.